# Can I use Dialyzer GUI or the dialyzer command line tool directly without dialyxir for elixir code?

Tags: erlang, elixir, dialyzer

I have an elixir project, on which when I run `mix dialyzer` (which calls dialyxir), I get a very small snippet of an error, and it becomes very difficult to trace the source of it. On dialyzer there are some additional format options available which do not seem to be available on dialyxir (like --format raw). How do I call dialyzer directly for an elixir project?

Comment: https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir#usage says `mix dialyzer --format raw` should work.

Comment: I think that was working till some earlier version, but on latest code this fails, the readme is incorrect.

Comment: I would love to know that too. Dialyxir is not well maintained, unfortunately